# VSCode WSL Weird Colors Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having the issue from these posts:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93356

https://dev.to/iamst0rm/fixing-vscode-color-bug-on-linux-185f

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I tried the solutions, but they didn't do much for me.

In a desperate attempt to fix it, I updated my Ubuntu to version Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS which kind of reduced the issue but I still have it.

I added `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true` as per this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration

Is there anything else I can do, did someone else experience this issue?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Not exactly a fix, but you could run VScode in Windows and remote into WSL

Answer (score 0):

I've had color issues, but not this severe graphical issue. I had tried to fix my color issues using the methods you linked. I found a solution that fixed it for me at least, you could give it a shot.

Go to this Google Docs document and follow the 5 steps under "Using colormgr from the command line". This fixed the issue on all Chromium-based applications by setting sRGB as the default color profile.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jMokB_OBkZVELu22li8vnHxAUoL1eGnLedP-1Gttv40/edit#heading=h.z8rbug83238e